# how to import project from github to computer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I have a rails + postgresql project hosted on github. I usually work on it from my laptop and push the changes out.

I would like the same project source to come on my desktop as well so I can work on it if I am on my desktop. The project is also deployed to heroku so I'd like to pull the db changes and stuff as well.

I already have github installed on my desktop. what commands/options can I run to get the code over to desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git clone {remote_path}
```

Comment: it says:
`github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errno=Connection refused
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection refused)`

Comment: Have you added your SSH credentials to your github account?